# Heroku file not found in release phase but exists in the release

Tags: node.js, heroku, github-actions

I've got a Node app deploying to Heroku from a github action workflow. My heroku procfile includes a release phase where migrations are run:

```
release: node packages/server/lib/entries/migrate.js
web: npm run start
```

The Heroku release log shows this error saying my `migrate.js` file is missing:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818

  throw err;

  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/packages/server/lib/entries/migrate.js'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)

    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)

    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

  requireStack: []

}
```

But I can confirm that the file exists in Heroku:

```
$ heroku run "ls -al /app/packages/server/lib/entries/migrate.js" --app my-app-name

-rw------- 1 u36913 dyno 3175 Jan  4 23:36 /app/packages/server/lib/entries/migrate.js
```

Also, my app is built before it's deployed to Heroku, so I've got the build disabled in Heroku:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "echo \"Skipping Heroku build.\"",
```

And here's the github workflow that's deploying the app to Heroku. I've confirmed that the workflow runs and performs the heroku deploy step (heroku shows the deploy as successful, but the release as failed).

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [master, github_workflow_heroku_deploy]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'
      - run: npm ci
        env:
          NODE_ENV: development
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/github_workflow_heroku_deploy' }}
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: 'my-heroku-app-name'
          heroku_email: 'my-heroku-email@example.com '
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that the `akhileshns/heroku-deploy` action uses git to deploy the project to Heroku, so my compiled `lib` directory wasn't being created. I'm not sure why the `lib` folder exists when I check manually in Heroku using `heroku run bash` and `heroku run ls`.

The fix is to force add and commit the build to github before running the heroku deploy action:

```
- run: git config --global user.email "email@example.com" && git config --global user.name "ci" && git add . && git add --force packages/server/lib && git add --force packages/shared/lib && git add --force packages/client/build && git commit -am "Deploy Heroku Commit"
```